# How can I change the Add to Cart button text on specific product forms?

Tags: 7, commerce

What is the easiest way to change the Add to cart form button text to something custom? I want to change the text only on certain product types. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take help of [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Get the ID of the form for the product display where you are trying to change the text & do something like this --

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){//replace your module name with MYMODULE
  if(strpos($form_id, 'commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-65') !== false){//my form ID is "commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-65", replace it with your form ID.
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Check Out');//Put the text which you want to make appear instead of "Add to cart".
  }
}
```

I also have several product display with custom text for "Add to cart". It took some time for me figure out the easy way. Have Fun :)

Comment: I'm using a Bootstrap module and I found this changed the class of the button from "btn-success" to "btn-default". I can't explain why but it is 100% repeatable :/

Answer (score -1):

The module works great.[stringoverrrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

Comment: This will change it site wide. OP wants to do it for just a certain product type.