# How can I rename the "Add Row" text on the button inside TableField

Tags: 8

I'm using the TableField module to allow users to add themselves as entrants to a running race.
I'd like to change the standard button text from "Add Row" to "Add Entrant".

I've pretty much zero Drupal development experience with regards to hooks and APIs and PHP however I'd like to know the best approach.

Option 1.
Do I use something like hook_form_alter() (like this:
[https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82106/how-can-i-change-the-add-to-cart-button-text-on-specific-product-forms]

Option 2.
TableField\src\Element\Tablefield.php
change:

```
'#value' => t('Add Row'),
```

to

```
'#value' => t('Add Entrants'),
```

I'm guessing this is a bad idea as any update to TableField could overwrite it.  However it seems a quick and dirty method which does actually work, so I'm tempted!

Comment: If you’re happy with quick and dirty, but don’t want the annoyance of the changes getting overridden, use a string override in settings.php: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/261153/2800

Comment: @Clive thanks for that.  Yes quick and dirty works for now :)